# Response for Brackets не запускается под Linux

Tags: linux, ide, adobe-brackets

В редакторе Brackets устанавливаю плагин **Response for Brackets**, нажимаю на иконку, а ничего не происходит. Перезагружал редактор. Без результатов.
Пробовал также ставить Response for Brackets original. Результат тот же

Comment: вероятно, следует написать сообщение об ошибке разработчикам.

Answer (score 1):

Заработало! Надо было открыть директорию в редакторе, чтобы запустился проект