# Linux Xubuntu косяк в редакторе кода Brackets

Tags: linux, ubuntu, adobe-brackets

Устанавливается без проблем но потом при добавление дополнения, возникает :
Внутренняя ошибка и всё на этом - ни какое дополнение не устанавливается, как это исправить ?
Я говорю о Emmet и Response в Brackets, в винду ставится без проблем а вот в Xubuntu нет! В чём может быть проблема и как её решить ?

Comment: Возможно повтор https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/467849/response-for-brackets-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-linux?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй запустить из терминала редактор. После дополни ответ тем, что туда напишет.

Comment: всё работает ! но  установить эти дополнение не возможно

Comment: смотрите в терминал при добавлении дополнений или ищите, где он логи хранит. без логов не разобраться.